Livewire 3.5 update on XAMPP (apache) server don't work error 400
i've a problem with the Livewire 3.5 on Apache hosted server. To test the library i created a simple laravel project with the normal
composer create laravel/laravel progettotest

then I've included the Livewire with the
composer require livewire/livewire 

The resulting composer.json is :
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5"
    },......


Now, the server have others Laravel projects, with her aliases, so, i configured the alias also for this basic project, like this :
Alias "/progettotest" "C:\PHP\progettotest\public"
<Directory "C:/PHP/progettotest/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>



Al the last i created the classic "counter" component in livewire, and this is the controller :
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}


and created the corresponding blade template :
<div>
    {{-- In work, do what you enjoy. --}}
    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
</div>

Changed the main blade template (welcome.blade.php) like this :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased dark:bg-black dark:text-white/50">
        <p>ciao</p>
        @livewire('counter')
        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>

changed the web.php to change the script route and the update route for the LiveWire:
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Livewire\Livewire;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::get('/progettotest/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
});
Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
    return Route::post('progettotest/vendor/livewire/update', $handle);
});


The page is loaded, no errors, the Livewire.js is loaded, but when i try to click on the plus button of the component, i've an error on the browser :

if I use the internal server of the php artisan serve, i haven't no errors... Anyone can help me?
Thanks.
I tried to change the path of the update route to livewire.js. I've tried to change the .htaccess of the main dir on the app, but the problem is always the same.

Only run
php artisan livewire:publish

